# Programmatically set color for the border of UITextField doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextField, I would like it having a height & round corner & a custom border color. I tried:

1. Select [image]
2. Create an @IBOutlet for TextField:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var messageInputField: UITextField!
   ```
3. In viewWillAppear , I have:

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       messageInputField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.71, blue:0.01, alpha:1).cgColor
       messageInputField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
   }
   ```

The output is:

[image]

The round corner works, but where is the color I specified in code? How to set the color I want for the border ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `messageInputField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0` or whatever `borderWidth` you'd like...

**Note that you can't use `roundedRect` if you want to use a custom border. For a custom rounded border do the following:**

1. Set the textfield's `borderStyle` property to `none`
2. Add a custom border by setting the textfield's layer's `borderColor` and `borderWidth`
3. To add rounded corners set the textfield's layer's `cornerRadius` to a value you wish
4. Override the textfield's `intrinsicContentSize` (or add a height constraint) to determine a default height
5. Override the textfield's `textRect` and `editingRect` to add correct insets

**Example:**

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomRoundedTextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit() {
        borderStyle = .none

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: 30)
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds).insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 0)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds).insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 0)
    }

}
```

Comment: Then, How to have a rounded corner and also custom border?